# Landscape server broke after update

Tags: server, updates, landscape

Good morning,

I applied Landscape updates to my Landscape server earlier today, and it is now failing to start. Logs seem to indicate a database schema update is required but I can't find out how to do this or what to update. I'm receiving these emails fairly regularly from the cron daemon on the landscape server:

```
<11>Apr 21 08:15:01 update-alerts: Traceback (most recent call last):
<11>Apr 21 08:15:03 update-alerts:   File "/opt/canonical/landscape/get-distributed-lock", line 7, in <module>
<11>Apr 21 08:15:03 update-alerts:     run()
<11>Apr 21 08:15:03 update-alerts:   File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/scripts/batch.py", line 76, in __call__
<11>Apr 21 08:15:03 update-alerts:     self.setup()
<11>Apr 21 08:15:03 update-alerts:   File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/scripts/batch.py", line 124, in setup
<11>Apr 21 08:15:03 update-alerts:     check_pending_patches(clean_stores=False)
<11>Apr 21 08:15:03 update-alerts:   File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/schema/verify.py", line 129, in check_pending_patches
<11>Apr 21 08:15:03 update-alerts:     raise RuntimeError("Databases need schema changes")
<11>Apr 21 08:15:03 update-alerts: RuntimeError: Databases need schema changes
<11>Apr 21 08:15:03 landscape-profiles: Traceback (most recent call last):
<11>Apr 21 08:15:04 landscape-profiles:   File "/opt/canonical/landscape/get-distributed-lock", line 7, in <module>
<11>Apr 21 08:15:04 landscape-profiles:     run()
<11>Apr 21 08:15:04 landscape-profiles:   File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/scripts/batch.py", line 76, in __call__
<11>Apr 21 08:15:04 landscape-profiles:     self.setup()
<11>Apr 21 08:15:04 landscape-profiles:   File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/scripts/batch.py", line 124, in setup
<11>Apr 21 08:15:04 landscape-profiles:     check_pending_patches(clean_stores=False)
<11>Apr 21 08:15:04 landscape-profiles:   File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/schema/verify.py", line 129, in check_pending_patches
<11>Apr 21 08:15:04 landscape-profiles:     raise RuntimeError("Databases need schema changes")
<11>Apr 21 08:15:04 landscape-profiles: RuntimeError: Databases need schema changes
<11>Apr 21 08:15:05 process-alerts: Traceback (most recent call last):
<11>Apr 21 08:15:06 process-alerts:   File "/opt/canonical/landscape/get-distributed-lock", line 7, in <module>
<11>Apr 21 08:15:06 process-alerts:     run()
<11>Apr 21 08:15:06 process-alerts:   File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/scripts/batch.py", line 76, in __call__
<11>Apr 21 08:15:06 process-alerts:     self.setup()
<11>Apr 21 08:15:06 process-alerts:   File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/scripts/batch.py", line 124, in setup
<11>Apr 21 08:15:06 process-alerts:     check_pending_patches(clean_stores=False)
<11>Apr 21 08:15:06 process-alerts:   File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/schema/verify.py", line 129, in check_pending_patches
<11>Apr 21 08:15:06 process-alerts:     raise RuntimeError("Databases need schema changes")
<11>Apr 21 08:15:06 process-alerts: RuntimeError: Databases need schema changes
```

in */etc/default/landscape-server*,

```
UPGRADE_SCHEMA="yes"
```

Where do I start?

Cheers,
James

Comment: Is there any more info about the schema changes in the logfiles, _e.g._, `/var/log/landscape/process-alerts.log`?

Comment: It's possible you're missing some of the required libraries - check out https://docs.ubuntu.com/landscape/en/landscape-install-manual#install-postgresql-and-required-libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic schema upgrade doesn't auto add missing dependencies. installing the missing package (`sudo apt-get install  postgresql-plpython3-10`) and running `setup-landscape-server` to migrate the schema is the way to unblock it, as per https://docs.ubuntu.com/landscape/en/ReleaseNotes19.10

Comment: This was the issue indeed - and when this module was installed the Schema update took place automatically. I was surprised this wasn't included in the dependencies of a regular apt upgrade though.